# Exception when deserializing a Templated class

Tags: c#, servicestack, deserialization

I've almost finished porting a Silverlight application from WCF to ServiceStack. Almost everything works, except the deserialization of a class:

```cs
public partial class MyClassResult<T> where T : class
{
    [DataMember]
    public T Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to deserialize a `MyClassResult<IList<myPOCO>>` I get a `null` value. But in Fiddler, the JSON seems correct.

I'm currently on 3.9.71, but I've just bought a 4.0 license.

Thanks

Comment: Your client is the ServiceStack `JsonServiceClient`, and you think the JSON from the server looks OK, but `ServiceStack.Text` in the client can't deserialize it? Can you post the JSON, and also include your relevant client side code that make the call?

Comment: Is there a problem deserialising `MyClassResult<myPOCO>` or just `IList<myPoco>`? There are no exceptions during the deseriliasation?

Comment: I've seen what happens...if I'm under the debugger I got the exception...otherwise no.... since It's a quite big json result is there a max default size limit? (I know it's not good to return big data) but I can't do pagination...

Comment: Well whats the exception. That will indicate the issue. It's just trial and error without out.

Comment: Big data sets shouldn't be a problem. If as you said ServiceStack managed to serialize it ok, it's like it can reverse it ok. But you should post the exception and the POCO that's causing the issue. Without these it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: I would paste the exception but VS tells StackOverflowException and inside I've no data at all....no stack, no inner exception....

Comment: Well that's helpful, a stack overflow exception generally does indicate too much data. You should try reducing your data set to a smaller list and see if it works. I know you said you can't page the results, but you should at least establish that it is the dataset size causing the issue, and work from there.

Comment: Also would still be useful to see the POCO(s) you are using.

Comment: That's ok it was a false problem... I had in VS 2013 Debug->Exception->CLR [Throw] removing it it works....

Comment: So you have resolved this issue? Or just not reporting the exceptions?

Comment: Here'm again....  the exception was not showing but I have a lot of those message in the callstack

Comment: ServiceStack.Common!ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.AsyncServiceClient.ReadCallBack<System.Collections.Generic.IList<myPOCO>>(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x272 bytes 
  mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Stream.BlockingBeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) + 0xc4 bytes

Comment: mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Stream.BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) + 0x74 bytes